# CakePHP: Modifying a related table's entry

Tags: cakephp

I'm still getting the hang of developing with CakePHP, however I'm running into a slight roadblock.

**The Problem:** Essentially I have posts with comments. What I'd like to do is have the most recently updated posts displayed at the top of their index page (So when a new comment is added to a post, then it pushes it to the top if it's the most recent).

I was thinking of accomplishing this by having a timestamp in the Post table called "updated" or something. Then whenever a new comment is added, the Post's updated field is modified. Then on the index, I display the posts according to their updated timestamp.

Would that be the best way to do it? if so, how would I modify that entry in the Posts table from the Comment controller? Or would I do that in the view form of the Comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Comment model's afterSave callback to update the timestamp.

But I think the best way to do this is using $this->[model]->saveAssociated() method from controller.
By having following structure in your comment submission, you can call 
`$this->Comment->saveAssociated($params);` from your Comments controller.

```
    //we know the Post.id
    $params => array(
       [Comment] => array(
                     'comment'=>'comment text',
                     'commented_by'=>'comment owner_id',
                   ),
       [Post] => array(
                     'id'=>1,
                     'commented_on'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                 )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have columns called "created" and "modified" in your SQL table, CakePHP will automagically handle the timestamps when you save data. You can then order your results in your controllers and views by most recently modified.

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        $posts = $this->Post->find('all', array(
            //Use ASC or DESC for ordering
            'order' => array('modified' => 'DESC')
        ));
        $this->set('posts', $posts);
    }
}
```

Try out that code in your controller then you can use debug($posts); either in the controller or in your view to see the results. Regardless, the docs have a ton of information on how to do these kind of things.

[CakePHP - Retrieving Your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)